# How to create thread according to integer value?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm trying to create thread according to integer value. For example if the variable is '5', program should create 5 threads or variable is '2', program should create 2 threads, etc. But I can't understand which path I must follow.

Comment: Have you tried using a `for` loop?

Comment: Downvoting due to the clear lack of research.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a matter of creating the Thread and start it. But I wouldn't suggest you to handle the thread explicitly, but to use Tasks or ThreadPool in order to execute multithreading work.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int numberOfRequestedThreads = 3;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRequestedThreads; i++)
        {
            var tempThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoWork));
            tempThread.Name = i.ToString();
            tempThread.Start();
        }
    }

    public static void DoWork()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thread#{0} is now working!", Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
    }
}
```